# While loop does not exit

Tags: java, replace, while-loop

While trying to write a simple java code to replace a particular character in a given string by using loop I have been much confused to find the mistake. Details are as below:

```
INPUT String : "123qq11 1q1 11q1 1qq11 1q1 11q1"


REQUIRED OUTPUT: "123QQ11 1Q1 11Q1 1QQ11 1Q1 11Q1"


GOT OUTPUT:   "Q23QQ11 1Q1 11Q1 1QQ11 1Q1 11Q1" as infinite loop
```

ALGORITHM: Replacing 'q' by 'Q' in given String.

My code to be corrected is:

```
public class Rani {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("123qq11 1q1 11q1 1qq11 1q1 11q1");
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < sb.length()) {
            while (i + 1 < sb.length()) { // while 2nd
                i++;

                if (sb.charAt(i) == 'q') {
                    j = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            sb.replace(j, j + 1, "Q");

            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Being new comer to java and programming I have been failed to manage the corrections.

Comment: Why do you have 2 loops here you only need 1...

Comment: apart from the issue what is the problem in simply doing [`"123qq11 1q1 11q1 1qq11 1q1 11q1".toUpperCase()`](http://ideone.com/kHF6qZ)

Comment: Also the problem is your second loop is never entered into when `i = sb.length() - 1` so `i++` never happens and `i` stays at `sb.length() - 1` forever...

Comment: This is where using your debugger would help but I think the code is just too complicated.  Just use one loop instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("123qq11 1q1 11q1 1qq11 1q1 11q1");
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < sb.length()) {
        while (i < sb.length()) { // while 2nd

            if (sb.charAt(i) == 'q') {
                j = i;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        sb.replace(j, j + 1, "Q");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Output:   123QQ11 1Q1 11Q1 1QQ11 1Q1 11Q1

Comment: Your correction has done a great favour to me. Only sharpness of mind can provide such to the point solutions to one's problem. I was knowing everything suggested by others, but I was keen to find my weak muscle. So your response is really of great value and educative. I am happy to find that on StackOver their are some mastermind persons like you who can help one to expand one's innovativeness and imagination.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you don't need `2` while loops.

Secondly `i` stays at `sb.length() - 1` forever making it an infinite loop.

You could use a `replace` or `replaceAll` instead.

```
String st = "123qq11 1q1 11q1 1qq11 1q1 11q1"
st = st.replace("q", "Q");
```

If you want to do it with while loops.

```
int i = 0; 
while(i < sb.length())
{
 if(sb.charAt(i) == 'q')
  sb.setCharAt(i, 'Q');
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use replace you can just do this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++)
    if (st.charAt(i) == 'q')
        st.setCharAt(i, 'Q');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("123qq11 1q1 11q1 1qq11 1q1 11q1");
         String strnew = "";
         for(int i=0;i<sb.length();i++)
         {
             if(sb.charAt(i)=='q')
             {      
                 strnew=strnew+"Q";

             }
             else
                 strnew=strnew+sb.charAt(i);
         }

         System.out.println(strnew);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

in your code you are telling i to increment too soon. in the inner loop `i` only gets to 30 while the length is actually 31. if you move the `i++` to the end of the first loop but our side of the inner loop it should work they way you want. like so:

```
...
if (sb.charAt(i) == 'q') {
                j = i;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
...
```

the only problem with that is you are always replacing the first character of the string. the first number "1" is being replaced with a "Q". becasue you are using `j` to replace "q" it is always the character at the 0th slot.

You could even make it simpler buy just using one loop:

```
while (i<sb.length()){
    if (sb.charAt(i) == 'q'){
        sb.replace(i, i + 1, "Q");
    }
    i++;
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

or you could use a for loop:

```
for (i =0; i<sb.length();i++){
    if (sb.charAt(i)=='q'){
        sb.replace(i, i+1, "Q");
    }       
}
System.out.println(sb);
```